# c# Handle space key event

Tags: c#, wpf

To begin, this may be repeats of previous questions, but none of those answers work.
For many of the examples, I dont even get the right procedures that are listed.

I have a `TextBox` and a `ListBox`. I want to enter an email in the text box, then when I push the `Space` Key, I need to add the email to the list box, then clear the text box.

As the title suggests, I have had no luck binding the space key.

I have tried:

```
    private void txtEmailAddr_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        KeyEventArgs ke = e;
        if (ke != null && ke.Key == Key.Space)
        {
            ke.Handled = false;
        }

        if (ke.Key == Key.Space)
        {
                lstEmails.Items.Add(txtEmail.Text);
        }
    }
```

And

```
    private void txtEmailAddr_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Space)
        {
                lstEmails.Items.Add(txtEmail.Text);
        }
    }
```

Please could someone help.

Comment: Have you added the appropriate eventhandlers to your form? (this can be done through the designer)

Comment: Such as the `KeyDown` event? Other than that - I never knew of any other used for this.

Comment: On a side note: I hope you mean "email address" and not "email". An email without spaces wouldn't look very readable.

Comment: >> Yes, @Shihan, an Email Address ...

Comment: What is the exact issue? Is the code being executed, but doesn't work as intended, or is it never even executed? Place a break point in your methods to find out.

Comment: It is supposed to substitute the Space key event with whatever i make it, but it doesnt, because the event is already handled

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using

```
public class SelectableTextBlock : TextBox
{
    public SelectableTextBlock()
    {
        AddHandler(KeyDownEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(HandleHandledKeyDown), true);
    }

    public void HandleHandledKeyDown(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        KeyEventArgs ke = e as KeyEventArgs;
        if(ke != null && ke.Key == Key.Space)
        {
            ke.Handled = false;
        }
    }
}
```

I am able to add that custom TextBox, which doesnt have the SpaceKey event handled.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of `KeyDown` event hook the `PreviewKeyDown` event for your textbox -

```
<TextBox PreviewKeyDown="txtEmailAddr_KeyDown"/>
```

From MSDN documentation -

Some key presses, such as the TAB, RETURN, ESC, and arrow keys, are typically
ignored by some controls because they are not considered input key presses. For
example, by default, a Button control ignores the arrow keys. Pressing the arrow
keys typically causes the focus to move to the previous or next control. The
arrow keys are considered navigation keys and pressing these keys typically do
not raise the KeyDown event for a Button. However, pressing the arrow keys for a
Button does raise the PreviewKeyDown event. By handling the PreviewKeyDown event
for a Button and setting the IsInputKey property to true, you can raise the
KeyDown event when the arrow keys are pressed. However, if you handle the arrow
keys, the focus will no longer move
to the previous or next control.

Comment: +1 Ahh, the old Preview event solution! Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

It does look like both methods should call the line `lstEmails.Items.Add(txtEmail.Text);`

Have you tried setting a breakpoint at that line to make sure it is getting called?

Are you sure you have bound the KeyDown event of the textbox to your method?

Like this:

```
nameOfYourTextBox.KeyDown += new EventHandler(txtEmailAddr_KeyDown);
```